# Angular not making CORS preflight

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, cors, lumen

I'm trying to build a new API using Lumen (even though I'm having second thoughts about that), and am trying to use [barryvdh's CORS package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors). I think I have it setup properly, so decided to do a simple request in angular to the default route setup.

With my current, manually setup API, when I make an API request, I always see 2 requests: the first being an OPTIONS request, the second being the POST/GET/DELETE/whatever. When I hit the Lumen api (on a different subdomain), I only see one request, being the POST or GET I'm testing. Both return me the expected results, but I still get the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`, presumably because there was no OPTIONS request?

Do I not understand CORS well enough? Is this expected? Do I not understand Lumen? I have no idea where I've gone wrong with this one.

Comment: CORS options are always declared on the server you're trying to access. It's the server that returns the message. Therefore, you need access to the (I presume) Lumen server (which I presume you can't access). So it's possible that Lumen needs you to declare your domain in their dashboard, or something.

Comment: This is an API I'm developing, so I'm setting up the Lumen app. Also, Lumen is a framework, so it doesn't have a dashboard; I have to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to intercept the OPTIONS request in Lumen and make sure it returns the cors headers. See https://gist.github.com/danharper/06d2386f0b826b669552 Also you can try and use Postman (a nice app for testing apis) to inspect if the headers were send correctly. https://www.getpostman.com/.The headers you are looking to add are

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type';
```

Note the headers can also be added to your web server instead of your app but that's not always a good idea.

Comment: Sorry. While I understand what you mean by capturing the OPTIONS request, but that's part of what I don't understand: when I make a request to the Lumen server, I don't see my app making an OPTIONS request, just the POST/GET I send.

Comment: Alright, going back over, I understand most of what you said now. The package I'm using, that I linked above, follows basically the same flow as the code you linked, but I guess doesn't work, most likely because I set it up improperly :/